# Reading Coordinates from c command in SVG-Path

Tags: svg

**Example 1:**

```
d="M151.5,85.5c0-36.48,29.52-66,66-66"
```

If I understand that correctly, then this defines the following coordinates for the Bézier curve: `A=[151.5, 85.5], B=[0.0, 36.48], C=[29.52, 66.0], D=[66.0, 66.0]`

**Example 2:**

But now I do have this command:

```
d="M4.35,174.28c4.16,0,8.33,.18,12.48-.04,6.26-.33,10.82-2.3,12.19-8.61,1.27-5.85-.81-12.77-9.08-14.09-5.23-.84-10.55-.11-16.07-.37"
```

If I read the coordinates using the same logic, then it would result in this:

```
A=[4.35, 174.28], B=[4.16], C=[0.0], D=[8.33], E=[0.18], F=[12.48, 0.04], G=[6.26, 0.33],
H=[10.82, 2.3], I=[12.19, 8.61],
J=[1.27, 5.85, 0.81, 12.77, 9.08, 14.09, 5.23, 0.84, 10.55, 0.11, 16.07, 0.37]
```

Why do those coordinates don't consist of x, y points as well?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData you seem to be ignoring the negative signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Path strings can contain tokens that separate other tokens. These comma/whitespace tokens consist of a sequence of zero or more whitespace characters, zero or one comma, and zero or more whitespace characters. The sequence is consumed as one token, and it is always optional.
   Exception: Before and after a command letter, no comma, only whitespace is allowed.
2. Path strings are being divided into tokens by consuming as many letters as possible that can be interpreted as either command letter, comma/whitespace or number. The next token starts immediately afterwards. That means that a comma might be there to indicate the end of a number, as a token of its own. But it must not, if a reason exists to stop consuming letters. That could be for example a negative sign. That sign is then read as part of the next token.
3. Lower case command letters indicate coordinates relative to the start of the current path segment.

Let's apply that to your path data.

```
M4.35,174.28c4.16,0,8.33,.18,12.48-.04,6.26-.33,10.82-2.3,12.19-8.61,1.27-5.85-.81-12.77-9.08-14.09-5.23-.84-10.55-.11-16.07-.37
```

Divide that into coordinate pairs. For ease of reading, every line holds one segment and starts with repeating the command letter. Every coordinate is relative to the last coordinate of the last line.

```
M 4.35,174.28 
c 4.16,0 8.33,0.18 12.48,-0.04
c 6.26,-0.33 10.82,-2.3 12.19,-8.61 
c 1.27,-5.85 -0.81,-12.77 -9.08,-14.09 
c -5.23,-0.84 -10.55,-0.11 -16.07,-0.37
```

Now the same in absolute coordinates. Every coordinate is in the same coordinate system.

```
M 4.35,174.28 
C 8.51,174.28 12.68,174.46 16.83,174.24 
C 23.09,173.91 27.65,171.94 29.02,165.63 
C 30.29,159.78 28.21,152.86 19.94,151.54 
C 14.71,150.7 9.39,151.43 3.87,151.17
```

These strings weren't produced by hand (apart form dividing them into lines). I used Inkscape, pasting the original string into a path data attribute. Then, I moved one control point with the keyboard one step forth and back again, which does not change the path, but triggers a recomputation of the path data.

Inkscape has several options to format the path strings. In the global preferences dialogue (Shift+Ctrl+P), select *Input/Output > SVG output*. You can choose between absolute and relative path string format, and you can force repeat commands.

Comment: Editing a single d-path one can do online: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks for the link, I'll be definitely using that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [**ccprog**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713037/reading-coordinates-from-c-command-in-svg-path/75713224#75713793): all `c` commands are relative.

Here's an example illustrating what happens when you use relative values as point coordinates.

```js
let pathData0 = path.getPathData();
showPathData(path, pathData0)

let pathData1 = path1.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});
showPathData(path1, pathData1)

function showPathData(path, pathData) {
  pathData.forEach((com) => {
    let values = com.values;
    let valuesL = values.length;
    if (valuesL) {
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
        renderPoint(path.closest('svg'), [values[i], values[i + 1]], "red", "0.75%");
      }
    }
  });
}

/**
 * render point
 * accepts coordinate array and point object
 **/
function renderPoint(
  svg,
  coords,
  fill = "red",
  r = "2",
  opacity = "1",
  id = "",
  className = ""
) {
  if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
    coords = {
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    };
  }
  let marker = `<circle class="${className}" opacity="${opacity}" id="${id}" cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
      <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

.col {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col">

    <p>Relative command values as points</p>
    <svg id="svg" viewBox="3.87 151.12 25.49 23.227">
  <path id="path" d="M4.35,174.28c4.16,0,8.33,.18,12.48-.04,6.26-.33,10.82-2.3,12.19-8.61,1.27-5.85-.81-12.77-9.08-14.09-5.23-.84-10.55-.11-16.07-.37" />
</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="col">

    <p>Absolute command values as points</p>

    <svg id="svg1" viewBox="3.87 151.12 25.49 23.227">
  <path id="path1" d="M4.35,174.28c4.16,0,8.33,.18,12.48-.04,6.26-.33,10.82-2.3,12.19-8.61,1.27-5.85-.81-12.77-9.08-14.09-5.23-.84-10.55-.11-16.07-.37" />
</svg>

  </div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

In the above example I'm drawing a circle at each command point.
As you can see, we can't use the relative values directly.
If you want to draw or move a new element to these coordinates, you need to **convert commands to absolute.**

I'm using the [`getPathData()` polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) by Jarek Foksa to parse and convert the pathData to all absolute.

It takes care of normalizing all possible separators and shorthand notations.

The optional normalize parameter will also convert all commands to absolute values `path.getPathData({normalize:true});`

As commented by ccprog:

The normalize parameter will also convert `A` (Arc) commands to cubic bézier curves.
Besides, it will also convert quadratic `Q`, commands to cubic as well as decompose all shorthand commands `V`, `H`, `T`, `S` to their longhand equivalent.

So I highly recommend, using a reliable/more advanced path parser for your language/environment – inother words you might run into troubles using a more simplistic regex based parsing approach (due to the plethora of shorthand notations).

Comment: I would not list the above "polyfill" library as a reliable parser. It contains at least one error (accepts negative numbers for the A command radius values), references a [spec](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths) that is not part of SVG 2, and does not implement that spec fully (R and B commands missing, altered behavior of Z command not implemented). Finally, option `normalize:true` will convert all curve commands to C command approximations, thus changing the path. Yes, that is part of the spec, but still: elliptical arcs cannot be expressed equivalently as cubic Beziers.

Comment: @ccprog: As always, you raised some important points.   
I've added the required info about the normalize parameter and clarified one shouldn't rely on too simplistic regex parsing approaches that might fail on a lot of occasions.
(BTW: I've never claimed in this post, that the aforementioned polyfill is a reliable or the most the most reliable path parser ;)

Comment: @ccprog: However, I dispute some of your arguments:
1. Negative numbers in radius values are also **tolerated** by most browsers – maybe browsers should be more restrictive. But no svg parser developer can be blamed for adapting this behavior.
2. "references a spec that is not part of SVG 2" – sure, since `getPathData()` method is still a draft for replacing `SVGPathSeg` and SVG2 specs are still evolving – So I agree that this "polyfill" must be considered rather as a library at the moment.

Comment: @ccprog:  3. **But the same applies to** not respected `R` Rom-Catmull or `B` bearings commands or the "altered behavior of Z command" (... documentation?): I think  these concepts are even way more experimental/futuristic than a native support for `getPathData` – so I also can't blame any developer to completely ignore these SVG2 features, while the specs are still "in flux".

Comment: It's not completely clear, but it seems the path spec is nowadays understood [as a SVG 2.1 draft](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/148). Re Z command, look at the third and fourth example at https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#PathDataClosePathCommand. For A command radii, you are right, see https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/paths.html#ArcOutOfRangeParameters.