# Commas in SVG path d attribute

Tags: svg

In the w3 spec for [elliptical arcs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), the parameters for the elliptical arc are listed as follows:
`rx`, `ry`, `x-axis-rotation`, `large-arc-flag`, `sweep-flag`, `x`, `y`.

The w3 spec also states:

> Superfluous white space and separators (such as commas) may be eliminated; for instance, the following contains unnecessary spaces:
> `M 100 100 L 200 200`
> It may be expressed more compactly as:
> `M100 100L200 200`

I am confused at why the commas are written as they are for the arc command in this example from mdn, in which the commas are as follows:  `rx`,`ry` `x-axis-rotation`,`large-arc-flag`,`sweep-flag` `x`,`y`

```html
<svg id="svg_css_ex1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M 10,30
       A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
        <!--    ^ ^    ^  -->
       A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
       Q 90,60 50,90
       Q 10,60 10,30 z
       " />
</svg>
```

And from the [w3 arc command example](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) the pattern repeats. Not only is there a comma separating the last set of `x` `y` coordinates, but there is also a comma in the middle separating the `large-arc-flag` and the `sweep-flag`.

```html
<svg width="12cm" height="5.25cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <path d="M300,200 h-150 a150,150 0 1,0 150,-150 z" />
  <!--                        ^       ^     ^             -->
  <path d="M275,175 v-150 a150,150 0 0,0 -150,150 z" />

  <path d="M600,350 l 50,-25
           a25,25 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25
           a25,50 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25
           a25,75 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25
           a25,100 -30 0,1 50,-25 l 50,-25"
         />
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't worry about comma or not, it is completely up to the author to use them or not. Compare [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713037#75713793) for the general rules.

Comment: commas **may** be eliminated. May indicates that they don't have to be.